# Can dark matter accumulate at Lagrange points?

Tags: dark-matter, lagrange-point

Interplanetary dust can accumulate at Lagrange points .

"Kordylewski cloud - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kordylewski_cloud

But can dark matter accumulate at Lagrange points and is there evidence for this for example between pairs of  galaxies or between the earth and moon?

Answer (score 7):

If dark matter is dissipationless and only interacts gravitationally, then no it can't. How could it be brought to approximate rest$^1$ with respect to a Lagrangian point, its inertia would mean it just carried on with whatever kinetic energy it had?

If dark matter is weakly interacting then it might be possible for it to accumulate in deep gravitational wells formed by ultra-dense matter - i.e. in white dwarfs or neutron stars. But such ultra-dense matter does not exist at Lagrangian points in the Solar System.

$^1$ Something "at Lagrangian points" (the wording of the question) is necessarily at rest on average with respect to those Lagrangian points. They are actually effectively in orbit around the more massive body. There is no mechanism to decelerate and capture dark matter into an orbit with a speed of $\sim 30$ km/s (e.g. for an orbit near Earth) when dark matter is travelling past the Sun with typical speeds of hundreds of km/s.

Even should one argue that the dark matter has a distribution of speeds and some of it will be travelling at close to zero velocity with respect to the Sun, that matter will be accelerated towards the Sun as it approaches and would stil not be captured at the Lagrangian points.

Comment: The smoother than expected profile of dark matter suggests to me that it does dissipate https://phys.org/news/2016-12-dark-smoother.html

Comment: Huh? It's *less* clumpy than expected. @DaveTheWave

Comment: @DaveTheWave Also, that article concerns scales much larger than what would be affected by dissipation in the dark sector.

Comment: temporary, reversible (-1) because I think you are oversimplifying the problem in order to write an easy answer. Associated with the regions of Lagrange points are unstable orbits that one can enter, then spend some substantial time in the general vicinity of a Lagrange point and the exit. That mechanism could result in a higher concentration without require inter-particle collisions or other lossy interactions. Accumulation ≠
 trapped, much less "at rest" as you stipulate.

Comment: Accumulate means rate of particles entering a volume  > rate of particles out that volume @uhoh

Comment: No, that's what *currently accumulating* means. Having accumulated means there's an excess density, but it could certainly be steady state. And it does not require "trapped" or "at rest" Do all explanataions for a ""Kordylewski cloud" require dust-dust collisions for its formation? (I don't know, but it's a good question)

Comment: Objects near Lagrange points aren't at rest. They maintain a constant relative position to the Sun and Earth, but that system is itself rotating.

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, in the parlance of the [restricted three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Restricted_three-body_problem) of which we speak (the only scenario where the L-points can be defined) *we work in a rotating frame of reference.* In this case the five [libration points](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35890/7982) (or Lagrange points) are indeed at rest because we let the pseudopotential take the place of centrifugal effects.

Comment: @ProfRob This is all so interesting! I'd never heard of these clouds before now, so I've just asked [Are dust-dust collisions necessary to explain Kordylewski_clouds at Earth-Moon L4/5? Aren't the cross-sections, number density timescales too small?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/54065/7982)